# Big Query table schema description

Tags: google-bigquery, schema, field-description

I have a BigQuery table that gets deleted and recreated/reloaded hourly by our scheduled job. How do I configure my process to add a description for each field each time the table is recreated?

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for:schema.fields[].description

check this out for reference:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource